# How to get the caller IP using Amazon API gateway and Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, ip, aws-api-gateway

I would like to get the caller IP in my Lambda function, I followed [this](https://github.com/marianzange/aws-lambda-geoip) and I have changed my body mapping in the integration request to look like this:

[image: my current configuration]
But my event object still does not have "requesterIp" in it.
Could anyone tell me what I'm missing out on?

Comment: What are the elements you have in event object?

Comment: i have the content of the request , in this case i'm sending {'x':15} and my function is just returning the event , the response contains {'x':15} as well , by the way before anyone asks , i deployed my api after doing these modifications

Comment: What you are showing here should discard your input payload and send this, instead, in the request body... shouldn't it?  It's a *body* mapping template.

Comment: Is your client code passing in a 'Content-Type: application/json' header? It will only use the mapping template if the Content-Type matches

Comment: Lorenzo de Lara : that perfectly solved my problem , thank you for your answer and sorry for the late response.

Comment: Anyone know how to get make sure the Request Body is also forwarded? With me I can get the sourceIP, but it drops the request body params.